# Как найти второе значение арксинуса?

Tags: c++, математика, stl, тригонометрия

Функция asin() в STL возвращают одно значение. Если взглянуть на таблицу синусов то можно заметить что одно значение синуса соответствует двум разным углам, например значение 0.5 соответствует углам 30 и 150 градусов. Функция возвращает значение 30 градусов в радианах. Каким образом можно получить второй угол для этого синуса? Аналогичный вопрос касается функции acos(). Вопросы конечно более математические, но может кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 9):

Вообще то это вопрос для 7-8 класса. Функция asin работает для диапазона -90 .. 90 (на самом то деле -PI/2 .. PI/2, но это и так понятно, дальше я все пишу в градусах - так легче). Для синуса парный угол посчитать легко - (180 - значение). Для косинуса - просто знак поменять (функция возвращает в диапазоне 0..180). Все другие значения можно получить, прибавляя/вычитая 360 нужное кол-во раз.

Answer (score 6):

для арксинуса таким "вторым" углом будет Пи - alpha, а для арккосинуса 2Пи - alpha. Где alpha - это "первый" угол

Comment: Спасибо, а то я с этими обратными тригонометрическими функциями голову сломал уже.

Comment: @some_guy это же вроде интуитивно понятно